# Program does not terminate when not using lazy val

Tags: scala

This is a solution to problem 14 on euler project.

But strange thing: this program does not terminate when val answer is not declared as lazy. While the val is lazy the solution is produced in seconds, without that java vm goes into 100% CPU usage for a long time (possibly forever).

```
package euler

object Problem14 {
//Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?

    def startingNumbersFrom(n: Long): Stream[Long] = {
        if (n == 1) 
            Stream(1)
        else if (n % 2 == 0)
            n #:: startingNumbersFrom(n/2)
        else
            n #:: startingNumbersFrom(3*n+1)
    }

            //This has to be lazy for program to terminate
    lazy val answer = (
        for (n <- 1 to 1000000) yield 
        (n, startingNumbersFrom(n).length)
    ).maxBy(x=> x._2)._1


    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        println(answer)
    }
}
```

Intuitively I can guess that the companion object is getting caught in init/tear down loop, but it is not apparent why that would happen.

Comment: I don't see this behavior. Both val and lazy val converge on the same solution in about the same time. Perhaps there is some other system problem?

Comment: change `startingNumbersFrom` from `def` to `val`, does this help?

Answer (score 1):

The program will terminate with `val answer = ...` but it will probably run out of resources before it does. Change `1000000` to a smaller number like `100` to see that it actually terminates.

The reason is does not work without `answer` as a `lazy val` is because the way it is evaluated. The `length` call on `startingFromNumbers` forces it to evaluate to a value. When `val answers` is strict the entire computation of `startingFromNumbers` occurs at each iteration. With small values like 100 this inefficiency goes unnoticed but at larger values recomputing at each iteration appears to run forever. Using `lazy val answer` the results `startingFromNumbers` are memoized to avoid repeated computation. So, as you discovered and Ryan answered make them both lazy or make them both strict.

Reducing the problem helps and adding a `println(n)` as the first call in `startingFromNumbers` helps visualize this.

```
scala> val answer = (for (n <- 1 to 3) yield (n, startingNumbersFrom(n).length))
1
2
1
3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
answer: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)] = Vector((1,1), (2,2), (3,8))

scala> val answer = (for (n <- 1 to 3) yield (n, startingNumbersFrom(n)))
1
2
3
answer: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Stream[Long])] = Vector((1,Stream(1, ?)), (2,Stream(2, ?)), (3,Stream(3, ?)))
```

In the first example we can see all the values are computed at each iteration. In the second  example only the first value is computed and the rest are delayed until needed i.e. lazy. If   `answer(i)._2` is evaluated with `toList` we can see the same numbers as in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to repro the problem on Scala 2.9.2. However, if I change your code to use a List[Int] instead of a Stream[Int], then the non-lazy version doesn't peg the CPU at all.

Comment: Hmmm, List[Int] would be just as good in this case since this is not an infinite stream, it must collapse to 1 eventually. But still curious to understand the nature of the problem.